# Tree list and pie charts in fastreport

Tags: fastreport, treelist

Is it possible to have a tree list in fastreports.net? The equivalent of a treelist in devexpress. And also a pie chart in fastreports? If these are possible please let me know how to get them in. I am using C# to design the report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, if you look at the demo application that comes with the fast report under the Interactive Reports, there is a option there that is called "Drill-Down Groups". That could be what you're looking for